# Persistence tools in C

Tags: c, persistence

I am looking for comfortable mechanisms for storing/restoring dynamically created data on disk. Data is a network of objects, interconnected by indexes or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I belive SQLite/MySQL would fit your needs, they have BLOB fields, indexing and quite fast and have lots of extra features.